# Seaborn TypeError when trying to plot a relplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to make a relplot  using seaborn but I am getting a TypeError because my Y values are of type float.

Here is the code and Dataframe for the plot.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
g = sns.relplot(x="Time", y="Total average Run", hue="Student Names", style="Student Names",
            col="Student Names", col_wrap=3,
            height=3, aspect=.75, linewidth=2.5,
            kind="line", data=first_mean).set(title='Diff First vs Second Run');
g.fig.set_figwidth(16)
g.fig.set_figheight(15)
```

DataFrame

```
  Total      Time     Student Names
0   0.00    09:00:00    Student A
1   6.20    10:30:00    Student A
2   -19.47  12:00:00    Student A
3   4.27    13:30:00    Student A
4   0.40    15:00:00    Student A
5   0.00    09:00:00    Student B
6   15.20   10:30:00    Student B
7   2.40    12:00:00    Student B
8   -5.80   13:30:00    Student B
9   -9.26   15:00:00    Student B
```

Error Traceback

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

TypeError: Invalid object type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3520/838149277.py in <module>
      1 # sns.set()
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
----> 3 g = sns.relplot(x="Time", y="Total average Run", hue="Student Names", style="Student Names",
      4             col="Student Names", col_wrap=3,
      5             height=3, aspect=.75, linewidth=2.5,
```

Comment: The x values seem to be problem. They need to be numerical (or datetime), not just strings.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks, I have been able to fix that.